# How to map NHibernate bag with a case-insensitive key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, one-to-many, nhibernate-mapping, case-insensitive

When I attempt to load an entity that has a child entity mapped as a bag, and the key between the child entity and the parent is a string, the resulting bag will not be populated if the key's case does not match the parent's ID property.

If *Office.ID == "**MyOffice**"* and *PromotionalContent.ContextKey == "**myoffice**"*, the collection does NOT load the promotions, *even though NHProfiler shows that it was returned by the database*.

If *Office.ID == "**MyOffice***" and *PromotionalContent.ContextKey == "**MyOffice**", *the collection DOES load*.

```
    <class name="Office" table="Office" lazy="true">
        <id name="ID" column="OfficeNum">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
      <property name="Name" column="OfficeName" />
      <property name="PhoneNumber" column="PhoneNum" />
      <bag name="Promotions" lazy="true" where="ContextType='Office'"  >
        <key column="ContextKey"/>
        <one-to-many  class="PromotionalContent"/>
      </bag>...
```

This is NHibernate version 4.0.3.

How can I map it, or *fix it* so that it always loads regardless of case?

Comment: what's the underlying database?

Comment: MSSQL 2014. I used NHProfiler I'm able to prove that SQL Server is returning the data for both cases, so it appears to be a problem with the session or the cache.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days trying to solve the problem using event listeners, debugging , turns out there is a bug in NHibernate.

**I was able to solve the problem by changing the actual NHibernate source, rebuilding and relinking.** 
*The technique I used leaves the actually entity keys untouched, which therefore preserves the case as it was when it came from or went into the database.*

When NHibernate loads an entity, a *"key"* is created that is basically just a *marker* that is stored and tested in an IDictionary<> that represents the session or a cache of entities and their related, dependent collections. This *"key"* was not smart enough to do a case-insensitive comparison. In order to do that, I had to modify the hashcode and tweak the Equals() to do case-insensitive comparison so that it always gets a hit if the case within the key is different from the test value.

**If you are comfortable building NHibernate and owning the tech debt until it is fixed, here is my patch:**

Modify EntityKey.cs, CollectionKey.cs, and CacheKey.cs

1. ***GetHashCode()*** - needs to return a consistent hash code regardless of the case of the key. Otherwise, Equals() will *NEVER* get called when the case is different.
2. ***Equals()*** - needs to return true regardless of the case. Otherwise, your entity and/or it's child collections will get missed.

*I cheated by simply using upper case for comparison, rather than doing the case insensitive compare.*

Sample Code:

*EntityKey.cs*

```
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var otherKey = other as EntityKey;
        if(otherKey==null) return false;

        if (Identifier is string && otherKey.Identifier is string)
        {
            object thiskeySanitized = ((string)Identifier).ToUpper();
            object thatkeySanitized = ((string)otherKey.Identifier).ToUpper();
            return otherKey.rootEntityName.Equals(rootEntityName) && identifierType.IsEqual(thatkeySanitized, thiskeySanitized, entityMode, factory);
        }
        return
            otherKey.rootEntityName.Equals(rootEntityName)
            && identifierType.IsEqual(otherKey.Identifier, Identifier, entityMode, factory);
    }

    private int GenerateHashCode()
    {
        int result = 17;
        object sanitizedIdentifier = (identifier is string) ? ((string) identifier).ToUpper() : identifier;
        unchecked
        {
            result = 37 * result + rootEntityName.GetHashCode();
            result = 37 * result + identifierType.GetHashCode(sanitizedIdentifier, entityMode, factory);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*CollectionKey.cs*

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        CollectionKey that = (CollectionKey)obj;
        if (this.key is string && that.key is string)
        {
            object thiskeySanitized = ((string)this.key).ToUpper();
            object thatkeySanitized = ((string)that.key).ToUpper();
            return that.role.Equals(role) && keyType.IsEqual(thatkeySanitized, thiskeySanitized, entityMode, factory);
        }
        return that.role.Equals(role) && keyType.IsEqual(that.key, key, entityMode, factory);
    }

    private int GenerateHashCode()
    {
        int result = 17;
        unchecked
        {
            result = 37 * result + role.GetHashCode();
            object sanitizedIdentifier = (key is string) ? ((string)key).ToUpper() : key;
            result = 37 * result + keyType.GetHashCode(sanitizedIdentifier, entityMode, factory);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*CacheKey.cs*

```
    public CacheKey(object id, IType type, string entityOrRoleName, EntityMode entityMode, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        key = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.entityOrRoleName = entityOrRoleName;
        this.entityMode = entityMode;
        object sanitizedIdentifier = (key is string) ? ((string)key).ToUpper() : key;
        hashCode = type.GetHashCode(sanitizedIdentifier, entityMode, factory);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        CacheKey that = obj as CacheKey;
        if (that == null) return false;
        if (key is string && that.key is string)
        {
            object thiskeySanitized = ((string)key).ToUpper();
            object thatkeySanitized = ((string)that.key).ToUpper();
            return entityOrRoleName.Equals(that.entityOrRoleName) && type.IsEqual(thiskeySanitized, thatkeySanitized, entityMode);
        }
        return entityOrRoleName.Equals(that.entityOrRoleName) && type.IsEqual(key, that.key, entityMode);
    }
```

The issue was reported to the NHibernate team back in 2015 - https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3833 .

Comment: Discarded as not being a bug. Databases can be case sensitive too. You may implement your own equality semantic by mapping your key with a custom type, as explained by Alexander on [NH-3833](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3833).

Comment: cool, thanks I will see if that works and post results. http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/10/15/mapping-different-types-iusertype.html